# Imagem não aparece no projeto HTML

Tags: html

Olá!

Estou começando a aprender HTML e, num projeto pessoal, não consigo colocar foto. Eu estou usando `<img src="html e css/img/teste.jpg">`

Vou colocar um pedaço do código aqui:

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <h1>Eu, Thaís Ketlen</h1>
  </header>
  <section>
    <header>
      <h2>Posts</h2>
    </header>
    <article>
      <header>
        <h3>Post #1</h3>
      </header>
      <p> Olá! Meu nome é Thaís e eu tenho 22 anos! Na foto, você pode ver como eu sou:</p>

      <img src="html e css/img/teste.jpg">
```

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Olá Thais tudo bem? Espero que sim

Pelo seu código eu notei que essa imagem encontra-se local no seu computador né?

Se for o caso, coloca o seu código html e as suas imagens numa mesma pasta. Dessa forma quando vc for usar a imagem de referência, você só vai precisar usar o "nome_da_foto.jpg".

Quando esse n for o caso, tente evitar usar espaços. Use o _ ou junte tudo.

Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 0):

Você não pode ter espaços no caminho para o arquivo. Tente substituir os espaços por `%20`:

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <h1>Eu, Thaís Ketlen</h1>
  </header>
  <section>
    <header>
      <h2>Posts</h2>
    </header>
    <article>
      <header>
        <h3>Post #1</h3>
      </header>
      <p> Olá! Meu nome é Thaís e eu tenho 22 anos! Na foto, você pode ver como eu sou:</p>

      <img src="html%20e%20css/img/teste.jpg">
```

Note que essa substituição deve ser feita apenas no arquivo HTML, e não no nome da pasta em si.

Answer (score -1):

Os editores de código não reconhecem um caminho de arquivo com espaço no nome do arquivo ou de alguma pasta, recomento utilizar o formato snake_case (separação_das_palavras_por_underline) ou CamelCase (Iniciando todas as palavras com letras maiúsculas mas sem espaço ) em pastas que você utilize para os projetos, isso facilita a compreensão do arquivo que vc está colocando e evita erros no código, além de ser um padrão utilizado na programação, aqui estão dois exemplos de caminho que vc pode utilizar:

```
<body>
  <header>
    <h1>Eu, Thaís Ketlen</h1>
  </header>
  <section>
    <header>
      <h2>Posts</h2>
    </header>
    <article>
      <header>
        <h3>Post #1</h3>
      </header>
      <p> Olá! Meu nome é Thaís e eu tenho 22 anos! Na foto, você pode ver como eu sou:</p>

      <img src="html_e_css/img/teste.jpg"> (snake_case)
                     ou 
      <img src="htmlECss/img/teste.jpg"> (CamelCase)
```

Answer (score -3):

Tente
<>img src="html-e-css/img/teste.jpg"<> e renomeie o nome da pasta com o traço "-" no lugar do espaço "spacebar".